# no. of solution of equation $\{f(f(x))\} = 0.5$

Tags: calculus

let $f(x) = 4x-2\;,0 \leq x\leq 1$ and $f(x) = -x^2-2x, -2 \leq x<0$

then find the number of solution of the equation $\{f(f(x))\} = 0.5$

$\{x\}$ is a fractional part of $x$

i am trying to find

$f(f(x)) = 4f(x)-2\;, 0\leq f(x)\leq 1$ and $f(f(x)) = -(f(x))^2-2f(f(x)), -2 \leq f(x)<0$

Am I not able to go further. Could someone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start by looking at the graph of $f(x)$. Its fairly straightforward.

[image]

Note that if $x>0.75$ then $f(x)>1$ and hence $f(f(x))$ is undefined for $x>0.75$.

Also note that when $x\in[0,0.5]$ the graph is less than zero so the function $f(f(x))$ is split into three section:

For $x\in[-2,0]$ we get $f(f(x))=4(-x^2-2x)-2=-4x^2+8x-2$

With some small calculations we get that this has a vertex at (-1,2) and end points of (-2,-2) and (0,-2).

For $x\in[0,0.5]$ we get $f(f(x))=-(4x-2)^2-2(4x-2)=-16x^2-8x$

With some small calculations we get that this has a vertex at (0.25,1) and end points of (0,0) and (0.5,0).

For $x\in[0.5,0.75]$ we get $f(f(x))=4(4x-2)-2=16x-10$

This has end points of (0.5,-2) and (0.75,2).

This looks like:

[image]

Lastly you need to consider the fractional part.

For $x\in[-2,-1]$ there will be 4 solutions as on that section $f(f(x))$ ranges from -2 to 2.

For $x\in[-1,0]$ there will be 4 solutions as on that section $f(f(x))$ ranges from 2 to -2.

For $x\in[0,0.25]$ there will be 1 solution as on that section $f(f(x))$ ranges from 0 to 1.

For $x\in[0.2,0.5]$ there will be 1 solution as on that section $f(f(x))$ ranges from 1 to 0.

For $x\in[0.5,0.75]$ there will be 4 solutions as on that section $f(f(x))$ ranges from -2 to 2.

So there is a total of 14 solutions.

For reference the graph of $\{f(f(x))\}$ looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**:-

We can break it into a system of equations as follows:-
$$f(y)=0.5$$
$$f(x)=y$$

First solve $f(y)=0.5$ to get (possibly multiple) solutions for $y$. Again solve $f(x)=y$ for all values of $y$ obtained.

Since you are only interested in number of solutions, a guess about range of y can be obtained by plotting together graphs of $y=f(x)$ and $y=0.5$ and then number of solutions for $f(x)=y$ can be guessed similarly for each $y$. Summing them gives them total number.

**ANSWER**:-

Check the graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/slb3vveks6).[image]

3 solutions for $y$: one in $(0,1)$ and two in $(-2,0)$.

If $y \in [0,1]$, you can visualize three solutions of $f(x)=y$ for each $y$.

If $y \in [-2,0)$, you can visualize one solution of $f(x)=y$ for each $y$.

Hence total number of solutions  $= 3\times 1 + 1\times 2 = 5$

Comment: You have not considered the fractional part mentioned in the question. You need to solve $f(y)=-1.5,-0.5,0.5,1.5$